# Passing strings variable with symbol " ' " to a function

Tags: javascript, objective-c, nsstring

I am calling to a javaScript function from my code in Objective C, and passing some strings. The strings should pass like that ('parm1','parm2')...

When I am passing my variables I can't add the symbol **'** to them...How can I pass it?
I tried this code:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"myJSFunction(%@%@)", parm1, parm2];
```

The result is a `function myJSFunction(param1,param2);` but as I checked only strings like that **'parma'** works in my function...

So I need to pass it like that `myJSFunction('param1','param2');`

How can I pass it?

Comment: I don't know what language/environment your working in, but have you tried: **[webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"myJSFunction(\'%@\'\'%@\')", parm1,parm2];** as it looks like a basic string format/replacement.

Comment: You have to escape them, your language should have an escaping function, otherwise do it manually by replacing `'` with `\'`.

Comment: I am using Objective C...so I should use `\'` for that symbol...OK thank's.

Comment: I'm not sure how Objective C escaping interprets it, so if `\'` doesn't work you may have to use `\\'` to escape the escape character (that's how it goes for PHP and JS at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a single string to `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:`, it doesn’t do format strings itself. So first you create your string, maybe using `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` and then pass that to your web view. Here is an example of how it could look:

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"myJSFunction('%@', '%@')", parm1, parm2];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString: js];
```

Comment: I tried that also,it's the same thing... my problem is how to set it with characters - ' before and after each parm.

Comment: You add those by adding them in your format string in front and behind the `%@` placeholder. Exactly the way I have written int in my example code.